# Фон в виде стрелки

Tags: html, css

Как на картинке, фон слегка похож на стрелку. Нужен наиболее верный способ[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Реверс-инжиниринг в помощь при наличие сайта

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с clip-path

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.block {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(67, 46, 59, 1) 0%, rgba(204, 142, 109, 1) 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(95% 0, 100% 38%, 95% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(95% 0, 100% 38%, 95% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  -webkit-clip-path: url("#clip-path");
  clip-path: url("#clip-path");
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip-path" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <polygon points="0.95 0, 1 0.38, 0.95 1, 0 1, 0 0" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```